# numpy linspace unexpected step value

Tags: python, numpy

Why does the following code does not result in `step=0.1`? I guess it is related to floating point precision, but then how to do it the 'right' way?

```
import numpy as np

lastprice = 3779

binsize = 0.1
minbin = round(lastprice*0.25, 0) - binsize/2
maxbin = round(lastprice/0.25, 0) + binsize/2
bincount = int((maxbin-minbin) / binsize)

bins, steps = np.linspace(minbin, maxbin, num=bincount, retstep=True, endpoint=False)


print(minbin)    
print(maxbin)
print(round((maxbin-minbin),0))
print(bincount)
print(steps)
print(bins)
```

The above results in the following output:

```
944.95
15116.05
14171.0
141710
0.100000705666502
[  944.95         945.05000071   945.15000141 ... 15115.74999788 15115.84999859 15115.94999929]
```

Comment: No, it's because `(maxbin - minbin) / binsize` is not integer. It almost is, though (`141710.99999999997`); if you change `int((maxbin-minbin) / binsize)` for `round((maxbin-minbin) / binsize)` or `np.ceil((maxbin-minbin) / binsize)` you get a step of `0.09999999999999999`, which may be good enough.

Comment: Correction: `(maxbin - minbin) / binsize` should be indeed integer (I didn't realize the numbers where picked for that), so it's a precision problem at that point (not in linspace).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I noticed this behaviour. But there should be however a solution to get a proper step=0.1, no? Alternativley, how to get to a list form minbin to maxbin with step size equal to 0.1?

Comment: You can do `minbin + np.arange(round((maxbin - minbin) / binsize) + 1) * binsize`, which may be more accurate. However, note [0.1 is periodic in binary](https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/), so it's impossible to get perfect results (if i take `np.diff` of my suggestion, I get up to seven different values very close to 0.1, actually about the same as the `linspace` solution)

Comment: Thank you, works fine! Sadly i don't see the difference. I would like to now how to avoid such unexpected results in the future.

Comment: Aha, 0.1 is periodic in binary, Thank you